# unsure how to connect rstudio with gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, rstudio

I'm trying to set up RStudio with gitlab. I have never used gitlab before, so i'm following set up instructions found online.

I created my gitlab account and project without any issues. I then followed the instructions found here for connecting RStudio with gitlab:

https://www.enricodata.com/post/setup-gitlab-with-rstudio/

The instructions say:
"In Rstudio go to Terminal and paste the following:

```
git config - - global user.email “YOUR EMAIL”
git config - - global user.name “YOUR NAME”
git config remote.origin.url git@gitlab.com:Allerious/code project.git"
```

When i execute the first two lines of code it outputs this in the console:
[image]

I'm unsure if this means it has done what it's supposed to have done.

Note: I did change “YOUR EMAIL” and “YOUR NAME” when running the code.

When i execute the third line of code it outputs this:

[image]

I'm thinking i should be changing the directory path to something else, but i'm unsure how to do this and what it should be changed to.

Here's another screen shot:

[image]

Maybe i should be changing the directory to one of these?

Comment: What is your problem? I don't understand...

Comment: The commands should be `git config --global ...`: note the missing spaces between the two `-` and between `--` and `global`. Also make sure you're using standard `"` symbols for `"YOUR EMAIL"` and `"YOUR NAME"`.

Comment: As to the third command, `git config remote` needs to be executed in a directory containing a git repository (just as the error message suggests!). `cd` to whatever directory you cloned your repository to before running the command. Nevertheless, I'm not sure why you'd even need this command, everything should be set up correctly after cloning the repository anyway.

Comment: thank you for the replies. They have solved my problem. :o)